# Google Chrome blocks links opened in new tab

Tags: google-chrome, popups

In Google Chrome, if I ctrl-click on a link to open it in a new tab, it is blocked by the Pop-Up blocker. How can I disable this behavior?

EDIT: I am not talking about disabling Pop-Up-Blocking in general. I am only talking about being able to ctrl-click on a single link and having the corresponding URL open in a new tab.

Comment: From James' answer that was really a comment: "Are you trying to allow all pop-ups to open up or just a website or just one page?" Please use the EDIT button to expand your question to make it more clear what you are doing, what you are experiencing, and what you are trying to accomplish.

Comment: It's also useful to indicate what Extensions you have installed, what version of Chrome you're running, what website you're starting on, what link you're clicking, and crucially if the problem repeats itself on a new PC with a clean install.  When you isolate the differences between the new PC with clean install -> your setup , you can usually find the cause of the issue.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

From the limited research I have done, this appears to be an issue with the latest Chrome update.  Some have said it is an issue with the Ghostery extension, and when it is disabled functions as "normal".  However many (myself included) do NOT have Ghostery installed and are still having the issue, although not on every link.  Unfortunately, without allowing ALL pop-ups, I haven't found a resolution other than right-clicking on the link and selecting "open in new tab".  This seems to mostly work.  Suspect just have to wait until they get it fixed and issue a new update.

Comment: Thank you, the culprit for me was indeed the Ghostery extension.

Comment: @vincent this is actually a Chrome bug; wait for Chrome v72 https://github.com/ghostery/ghostery-extension/issues/254

Comment: I don't have Ghostery and can't reproduce the problem.

Comment: The [Chromium bug thread](https://bugs.chromium.org/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=918268) mentions some other extensions that also trigger the problem.

Comment: This bug is so annoying. Can't wait for v72

Answer (score 1):

Try to update iThemes Security to 7.3.1 if you use it on WordPress ;)

"Bug Fix: Tabnapping: Apply noopener to links instead of using blankshield script when available to prevent new pop-up blocker behavior from killing the links."

If you are not in this case, you probably have a javascript event on your external links that is causing the issue.